# Definite integral of x times Gaussian

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

I am tryng to solve the following definite integral:

$$ \int _ 0^\infty x \, \exp \left( {-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2} \right) \, dx
$$

I have tried making the substitution $u = (x-\mu)/\sigma$, which allowed me to divide the integral into what I think are two simpler integrals:

$$
\int _ 0^\infty x \, \exp \left( {-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2} \right) \, dx \, = \, \int _ {-\mu/\sigma}^\infty (u\sigma + \mu) \, \exp \left( {-\frac{u^2}{2}} \right) \, \sigma \,du \\
$$
$$ = \int _ {-\mu/\sigma}^\infty u \, \sigma^2  \, \exp \left( {-\frac{u^2}{2}} \right) \, du \quad+\quad \int _ {-\mu/\sigma}^\infty \mu \, \sigma  \, \exp \left( {-\frac{u^2}{2}} \right) \, du
$$

The one on the left can be solved with some help from [wolfram-alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int%20%5Csigma%20%5E%202%20*%20u%20*%20exp%28-u%5E2%2F2%29%20du%2C%20u%3D-%5Cmu%2F%5Csigma..inf), and turns out to be $\sigma^2\,\exp(-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2})$. However, I don't know how to handle the one on the right. I have the vague intuition it can be somehow expressed in terms of the Cumulative Density Function (CDF) of a normal distribution, but not sure how to make that work.

Comment: It will need to be expressed in terms of the error function

Comment: For the second integral, I understand you can un-do the substitution ($\sigma$ goes away because $du = dx / \sigma$):

$$
\int _ {-\mu/\sigma}^\infty \mu \, \sigma  \, \exp \left( {-\frac{u^2}{2}} \right) \, du = \int _ {0}^\infty \mu  \, \exp \left( -\frac{1}{2}\left({\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}} \right)^2 \right) \, dx
$$

Then, I think it can be evaluated using the normal CDF as follows:

$$
\int _ {0}^\infty \mu  \, \exp \left( -\frac{1}{2}\left({\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}} \right)^2 \right) \, dx = \sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2} \mu \, \left( 1-\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma).\text{cdf}(0)\,\right)
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s continue OP’s journey by letting $y=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_{-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}}^{\infty}(\sigma y+\mu) e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^2} \sigma d y \\
& =\sigma^2 \int_{-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}}^{\infty} y e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^2} d y+\mu \sigma  \int_{-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}}^{\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2} dy\\
& =-\sigma^2 \int_{-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^2} d\left(-\frac{y^2}{2}\right)+\mu \sigma\sqrt{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{\mu}{\sqrt 2 \sigma}} e^{-v^2} d v \textrm{ where }v=\frac{-y}{\sqrt2}  \\
& =-\sigma^2\left[e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^2}\right]_{-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}}^{\infty}+\mu \sigma\sqrt{2} \cdot\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi}\left[\operatorname{erf} \left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma} \right) +1\right]\\
& =\sigma^2 e^{-\frac{\mu^2}{2 \sigma^2}}+\mu \sigma\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left[\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2} \sigma}\right)+1\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: At some point you start using $u$ instead of $\mu$ in one of the integral limits. Was that intentional or a typo? If intentional, why?

Comment: Thank you very much. They are typos.